# Error granting permissions

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench, privileges

I'm using MySQL Workbench, and MySQL 5.6.

I am trying to create a user that can only execute stored proceedures.

So I created a user, gave a password and gave the role 'routine.execute'.

It generates this:

```
CREATE USER 'serveruser' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

GRANT EXECUTE ON ROUTINE `myschema`.* TO 'serveruser';
```

And that generates this error:

```
Executing SQL script in server

ERROR: Error 1064: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '`myschema`.* TO 'serveruser'' at line 1





GRANT EXECUTE ON ROUTINE `myschema`.* TO 'serveruser'



SQL script execution finished: statements: 228 succeeded, 1 failed
```

However, if I select any other role, like owner or table.insert, it goes through just fine.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try changing to:

```
GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `myschema`.* TO 'serveruser'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
CREATE USER 'serveruser' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';

GRANT EXECUTE ON PROCEDURE `myschema`.* TO 'serveruser';
```